# R P-value glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I have code this code below

```
gl <-
    cv.glmnet(
      x = mm,
      y = reg_base$eff_score,
      offset = NULL,
      nfolds = 10,
      alpha = 0,
      family = "gaussian"
    )
```

which outputs the 41 betas.

My question is:

**How to get the p-value for each beta? Is there special method for it? I need to decide which betas are significant**

Comment: p-values for penalized models (lasso/ridge/elasticnet) are an open and challenging statistical question ("post-selection inference"). People often refit the model using `lm()` with only the "selected" parameters [non-zero estimated coefficients], but this is a **bad idea** in general (requires extremely strong assumptions to hold: see Zhao, Sen, Ali Shojaie, and Daniela Witten. “In Defense of the Indefensible: A Very Naive Approach to High-Dimensional Inference.” ArXiv:1705.05543 [Math, Stat], December 7, 2017. http://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05543.)

Comment: Can It be argued that the parameter estimates obtained by glmnet are already statistically significant?

Comment: not particularly. If you want guidance on p-values for penalized regressions you might ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224796/why-are-confidence-intervals-and-p-values-not-reported-as-default-for-penalized)